# Django Models - Link types specific to a business, only one link type per business?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I modify the following models, such that each business is allowed only one social media link of each type:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    business = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class SocialLinkType(models.Model):
    FB = 'FB'
    TWTR = 'TWTR'
    PIN = 'PIN'
    INST = 'INST'
    MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES = (
        (FB, 'Facebook'),
        (TWTR, 'Twitter'),
        (PIN, 'Pinterest'),
        (INST, 'Instagram'),
    )
    business = models.ManyToManyField(Business) 

class SocialLink(models.Model):
    link_url = models.TextField()
    link_type = models.ForeignKey(SocialLinkType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: I would suggest to override the default save method on the SocialLink model to check if there is already a SocialLink model entry for with the certain type for the certain Business

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an answer on how that would look. Also if you can think of a way to solve this, without having to override the save method, that would be preferable, not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sociallinktype model add names like facebook, twitter,....

```
class SocialLinkType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

In sociallink model add unique_together to make sure each business has only one facebook link....

```
class SocialLink(models.Model):
    link_url = models.TextField()
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    link_type = models.ForeignKey(SocialLinkType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['business', 'link_type']
```